# Running DL Training on CUDA GPU (util 98%) does not impact gaming? Are CUDA cores not Render Cores?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, gpu, cuda

I downloaded `CUDA 11` to run some heavy (and I mean it, heavy) DL model training tasks that use low memory (2GB). I'm rocking a `3070 Ti` with `8GB`. However in task manager I can see `CUDA` utilization is at `98%`, and my 3D is about `20%`.
However when I play `Fortnite`/`Rocket league` my GPU `temperature` remains the same, `CUDA` remains the same, `3D` goes up to `70`/`80%`, and yet my FPS remain a constant `144` at the Max settings of both games, as if there is 0 FPS effects. So my question is how is this possible? What are `CUDA` cores exactly and are they not the same used for rendering graphics? I did read and they say that `CUDA` is a way to access Shaders, but AFAIK Shaders are also a requirement in games. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Updated with a link to Task Manager and GPU-Z

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQVKJ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer due to helpful users on reddit:
The specific application I was using has a load balancer that prioritizes full-screen apps.